# Как заполнить элемент в фокусе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, я новичок в jquery, хочу написать судоку и пытаюсь его как-то заполнить с клавиатуры. Мне нужно:

1. При клике взять ячейку `$("table td")` таблицы в фокус.
2. При нажатии на кнопку клавиатуры ввести значение в ячейку в фокусе.
3. Сразу сбросить фокус.

Или же просто ввести код кнопки в ячейку, дальше думаю разберусь. Я сколько не гуглил, так и не понял как это сделать. Видел примеры как брать элемент в фокус или как слушать клавиатуру, но видимо мои познания jquery слишком слабы, чтобы понять как соединить это вместе )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делаю чучуть не так. При нажатии на ячейку - я ее запоминаю, а фокус передаю в инпут. И потом значение инпута передаю в ячейку.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var Input = $('#someval');
  var CurTr = false;
 
  Input.on('keyup',function(){
    if(CurTr) {
      CurTr.html($(this).val());
      $(this).val("");
      $(this).blur();
      CurTr.removeClass('SelTr');
      CurTr = false;
    }
  });
  
  
  $('#sometable').find('tr td').on('click',function(){
    
    CurTr = $(this);
    CurTr.addClass('SelTr');
    Input.focus();
  });
  
});
```

```css
#sometable tr td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#someval {
  position:fixed;
  left:-100%;
}

.SelTr {
  background: rgb(234, 244, 148);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="someval">
<table id="sometable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Если <input id="someval"> сделать скрытым, то у меня перестает работать код. Видимо не может взять в фокус это поле.

Comment: ну как вариант: visibility:hidden; или position:fixed; left:-100%. В примере код подправил.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var clickedTd = null;
    var tableTDs = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('td');

    for(var i = 0; i <tableTDs.length; i++) {
        tableTDs[i].onclick = function () {
            if(clickedTd != null) {
                clickedTd.style.background = 'white';
            }
            this.style.background = '#f7ffcc';
            clickedTd =  this;
        }
    }

    window.onkeyup = function(e) {
        var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if(key >=48 && key <=57 && clickedTd !=null ) {
            clickedTd.innerHTML = key - 48;
        }
    }
```

```css
table{
        margin: auto;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        background-color: mintcream;
        text-align: center;
        border: 3px solid black;
    }

    table td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<table id="table" >
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```